# Create a regex that just allows specific characters

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex that just allows the following characters: `0`-`9`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `.`, but it should not be necessary to match all of them it could be that it matches just two or three of them. At the time I have this `^[0-9./+*-]` but it doesn't work and I have no Idea why.

Does anyone nows how I can fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘not [...] necessary to match all of them’? Could you show us some sample data, preferably both positive and negative cases? Moreover, which language/regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape special characters, like the `/`, and to add `*` for allowing one of the following to be more than once:

```
[0-9.\/+*-]*
```

See working example: https://www.regex101.com/r/yL5iH4/1

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and competently help.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex looks good, but only accepts a single letter (at the beginning of the line because of the `^`).

If you want to allow zero or more of these characters, try adding a * to the end, like so:

```
^[0-9./+*-]*
```

... one or more characters:

```
^[0-9./+*-]+
```

... exactly 7 characters:

```
^[0-9./+*-]{7}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The dash doesn't need to be escaped if it's the last character in the class.

Comment: Whoa, you're correct. Then I suppose the original problem must be that this regex only allows a single character?